# Python file not emailing result success via Task Scheduler but emails result success via Command Prompt

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, command-prompt, python-3.7, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to get a Task Scheduler job to execute a python script daily which does some tests and sends the results to me via email.

In the Actions section I put into the Program/Script field: \ServerName\FolderName\Python Script

When I run this it will run for a few minutes then not produce an email with results. However when I go to the script location and run a command prompt, then run the python script from inside command prompt it will run successfully and send me the email.

I have tried using the "Add arguments" and "Start in" sections of the Action section in Task Scheduler.

I have also tried to call a batch script to call the python script which also does not work except when running through command prompt like I did with just the python script.

I am also running the below general settings in Task Scheduler [Task Scheduler settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBpwv.png)

Any advice on what I am missing would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, try to more info from the windows system event viewer (eventvwr).